# nginx rewrite / redirect

Tags: nginx

Assuming I have 1000 URLs that look like these

- http://www.mydomain.com/pet/cat/info
- http://www.mydomain.com/pet/dog/info
- ...
- http://www.mydomain.com/pet/fish/info

Each URL should return a corresponding html file in the /usr/local/nginx/data directory.

- /usr/local/nginx/data/cat.html
- /usr/local/nginx/data/dog.html
- ...
- /usr/local/nginx/data/fish.html

What construct should I use to map all of them at once?
Can you please provide a code snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out how to do it.

```
...
location ^~ /pet {
    root     /usr/local/nginx;
    rewrite  "/pet/([^/]+)/info$"  /data/$1.html  break;
}
...
```